# Google Maps API: adding zip code boundaries

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps JS API to place some markers on a map.  The code is very simple. I just create the map using "new google.maps.Map" and then create each marker with "new google.maps.Marker".

In addition to displaying the markers, I aso want the map to display the boundaries of one particular US zip code.  I've found that the Google Maps website will display the boundaries of a single US zip code if you go to a URL that looks like https://www.google.com/maps/place/14618 or https://www.google.com/maps/place/94703.

Can anyone show me how to use the Google Maps API to display US zip code boundaries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a source for zip code boundaries. For instance, it can be [ZIP Code Tabulation Areas](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/kml/kml_zcta.html). US Census Bureau provide kml files and Google Maps API has [KmlLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer) which can be put together like this:

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 11,
  center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
})
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
  url: 'http://anatolysukhanov.com/94703.kml',
  map: map
})
```

```css
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
  </head>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.

I'm not sure why this question is considered too broad. I asked a question, and the answer given was very useful.